# How to solve the error found invalid character; only `#` is allowed in raw string delimitation? (Rust)

Tags: events, rust, near

I'm new to Rust and Near Protocol. During training I faced the following problem:
If you follow the example `log!( r#"EVENT_JSON:{"standard": "nepXXX", "version": "1.0.0", "event": "YYY", "data": {"token_id": "{}"}}"#, token_id );` of https://nomicon.io/Standards/EventsFormat, it gives an error 'Invalid format string'.

If the quotes are " replaced by ' `log!( r#'EVENT_JSON:{"standard": "nepXXX", "version": "1.0.0", "event": "YYY", "data": {"token_id": "{}"}}'#, token_id );`, then this error disappears, but during the build contract gives the following error: [image error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pf1gl.png)

How can this problem be solved?

Comment: Do not post images as text. And post the full error in both cases.

Comment: `{` and `}` have special meaning in a format string. You need to double them `{{`/`}}` in order to escape that behavior